# Type 'Observable<Post | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Post>'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am just starting with Angular and I am trying to build a Blog with Firebase + Angular. However, I am getting an error which I can't understand how to fix. I have a `blog.service.ts` file where I am putting the different services. The issue is with the `getPostById()` method where I get the above error. Here is a link to the GitHub repo: **https://github.com/achakarov/blogsite-angular**

Here is the code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Post } from '../models/post';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class BlogService {
  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {}

  createPost(post: Post) {
    const postData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(post));
    return this.db.collection('blogs').add(postData);
  }

  getPostbyId(id: string): Observable<Post> {
    const blogDetails = this.db.doc<Post>('blogs/' + id).valueChanges();
    return blogDetails;
  }
}
```

Here is my `blog-card` component in which I use the service:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { BlogService } from 'src/app/services/blog.service';
import { Post } from 'src/app/models/post';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-blog-card',
  templateUrl: './blog-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blog-card.component.scss'],
})
export class BlogCardComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  blogPost: Post[] = [];
  private unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(private blogService: BlogService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getBlogPosts();
  }

  getBlogPosts() {
    this.blogService
      .getAllPosts()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
      .subscribe((result) => {
        this.blogPost = result;
      });
  }

  delete(postId: string) {
    // Method definition to be added later
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
    this.unsubscribe$.complete();
  }
}
```

Finally, the `post.ts` file is as below:

```
export class Post {
  postId: string | undefined;
  title: string | undefined;
  content: string;
  author: string | undefined;
  createdDate: any;

  constructor() {
    this.content = '';
  }
}
```

Can someone PLEASE help me fix this as I am having my head banging against the wall?

Comment: what is in getAllPosts?

Comment: getAllPosts(): Observable<Post[]> {
    const blogs = this.db
      .collection<Post>('blogs', (ref) => ref.orderBy('createdDate', 'desc'))
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map((actions) => {
          return actions.map((c) => ({
            ...c.payload.doc.data(),
            postId: c.payload.doc.id,
          }));
        })
      );
    return blogs;
  }

Comment: Try to set the type on the const blogDetails -> const blogDetails: Observable<Post> = this.db.doc<Post>('blogs/' + id).valueChanges();

Comment: @LarsRødal same :(

Answer (score 1):

> Type 'Observable<Post | undefined>' is not assignable to type
> 'Observable'

Errors like this are because of type checking and the error describes the issue very well. The problem is that type checking in that course might not be as strict as it is in your project. Angular 12 doesn't even ask on project creation if you want to use the 'strict mode' and just defaults to strict now.

You basically can't set an object that could return `undefined` to a variable that is expected to be defined.

Depending on your situation and the desired behavior either:

- Use `Observable<Post | undefined>` for type of the receiving value
- Make a check if the incoming observable isn't of type `undefined`:

  ```
  if (yourObs != Observable<undefined>){
     your logic...
  }
  ```
- In other cases you can use the definite assignment (!) behind a variable to tell the compiler to rest assured the variable will be assigned (I don't think this will help in your case though)
- Turn off strict mode in your project (I would not advise this. It's best to learn to work with strict typing)

Comment: Thank you very much for the provided clarifications, they are very useful. I tried these, but still getting the same error. I don't want to try turning off the strict mode.

Comment: If you make a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) we can more easily help solve your problem.

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 Here is a link to the GitHub repo: https://github.com/achakarov/blogsite-angular

Answer (score 0):

Update `getPostById` method to return `Observable<Post|undefined>` instead of `Observable<Post>` because you could potentially return undefined in that method.

Comment: I tried this, but then I get a fat error in the blog.component.ts: 

"No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 5, '(observer?: PartialObserver<Post | undefined> | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(result: Post) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PartialObserver<Post | undefined> | undefined'.
      Property 'complete' is missing in type '(result: Post) => void' but required in type 'CompletionObserver<Post | undefined>'....